What should be the NodeClassRef for Karpenter's NodePool in GKE?
I have created a GKE cluster in GCP and wanted to install Karpenter on it for the autoscaling. While trying to install Karpenter, pods gives the error asking to create the NodeClaim resource which requires NodeClassRef (https://github.com/aws/karpenter-provider-aws/blob/main/pkg/apis/crds/karpenter.sh_nodepools.yaml).
I can find the NodeClassRef object for the AWS i.e. EC2NodeClass, but I can't find it for the GCP. The documentation says that the NodeClassRef will be different for the different cloud providers (https://karpenter.sh/docs/concepts/nodeclasses/).
I want to know what NodeClassRef I should use GCP and how?

As per documentation v0.36 (latest):

To use Karpenter, you must be running a supported Kubernetes cluster on a supported cloud provider. Currently, only EKS on AWS is supported.

https://karpenter.sh/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-karpenter/
